# How to handle Ctrl-Z with InteractiveConsole?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6

I have a simple snippet:

```
import code
class d(code.InteractiveConsole):
  def runsource(self, source, filename):
    print 'mongoose rocking ', source, ' ', filename
    return code.InteractiveConsole.runsource(self, source, filename)

d1 = d()
d1.interact()
```

This works exactly as expected, except for one bit: Enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in the python prompt to suspend the process. When I press fg from the shell prompt, the process just goes away. I suspect the signal is not handled but I don't understand why - when I run Python otherwise <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> works just fine. What am I missing here?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Python 2.7.9 on FreeBSD 10.1 : Ctrl-Z + fg in the shell prompt returns in same prompt level (with your code I still see *mongoose rocking*)

Comment: i am on python2.7 in mac osx10.7.4

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "process just goes away"?